# How to set the content of an HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

An HttpWebRequest has the properties ContentLength and ContentType, but how do you actually set the content of the request?

Comment: here is a simple tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength.aspx

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following should get you started

```
byte[]  buffer = ...request data as bytes
var webReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/target");

webReq.Method = "REQUIRED METHOD";
webReq.ContentType = "REQUIRED CONTENT TYPE";
webReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

var reqStream = webReq.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqStream.Close();

var webResp = (HttpWebResponse) webReq.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Though it may be obvious to some, make sure to set the Content Type BEFORE writing to the request stream.

Answer (score 8):

.NET 4.5 (or .NET 4.0 by adding the [Microsoft.Net.Http](http://nuget.org/Packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) package from NuGet) provides a lot of additional flexibility in setting the request content. Here is an example:

```
private System.IO.Stream Upload(string actionUrl, string paramString, Stream paramFileStream, byte [] paramFileBytes)
{
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(paramString);
    HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(paramFileStream);
    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(paramFileBytes);
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(stringContent, "param1", "param1");
        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", "file1");
        formData.Add(bytesContent, "file2", "file2");
        var response = client.PostAsync(actionUrl, formData).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have an example on how to call this function? should I create the Web request ( request)  first , set the content type (request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),  method = Post, content length,  then  do a Stream (e.g. Stream dataStream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream();)   And after that pass it to the parameter paramFileStream ?  like this? Stream uploadstream = Upload(actionUrl, paramString, dataStream, byteArray);  ?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a different option for posting info without messing with Bytes and Streams. I personally find it easier to follow, read, and debug.

```
// Convert Object to JSON
var requestMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObject);
var content = new StringContent(requestMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

// Create the Client
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(AuthKey, AuthValue);

// Post the JSON
var responseMessage = client.PostAsync(requestEndPoint, content).Result;
var stringResult = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

// Convert JSON back to the Object
var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(stringResult);
```

Comment: Where is StringContent from?

Comment: Oh you are using Microsoft.Net.Http, which is new and a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

HttpWebRequest's RequestStream is where the action is at - rough code...

```
//build the request object
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http://someapi.com/);
//write the input data (aka post) to a byte array
byte[] requestBytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(inputData);
//get the request stream to write the post to
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
//write the post to the request stream
requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
```

If you're sending extended chars, use UTF8Encoding, make sure you set the right content-type/charset header too.

Comment: need to set the method on the request as well - and usually also the contenttype

Comment: yeah sure Robert - I left out *a lot of code* like actually sending the request too :) It's good for the OP and brevity to complete the dots. I marked it as a community answer if you want to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` gets the request Stream.  After you have set the headers, use `GetRequestStream()` and write the content to the stream.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) explains how to transmit files using `HttpWebRequest`, which should provide a good example of how to send content.

But, basically the format would be

```
 var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
 stream.Write( stuff );
 stream.Close();
 var response = request.GetResponse();
```