# c# getting time out every time on HTTP web request

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

My Request

```
 lobjRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RequestURL);
 lobjRequest.Method = pstrRequestMethod;
 lobjRequest.Proxy = Helper.CreateProxyFromSettings();

 lobjRequest.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(pstrRequestText);
 lobjResponse = (HttpWebResponse)lobjRequest.GetResponse();
 //Time out here
```

Internet available but getting time out every single time...After system wakeup from sleep (4 - 5 hr)

Comment: What does 'After system wakeup from sleep' have to do with this?

Comment: Application just check internet if its available then start sending request to server for and at that time timeout loop start..

Comment: How do you know the server is working?

Comment: I see no code that actually sends `pstrRequestText` along with the request. Did you leave that out here, or did you not write that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the content of an HttpWebRequest in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527316/how-to-set-the-content-of-an-httpwebrequest-in-c)