# Upload file to apache server using httpclient **with example**

Tags: c#, apache, tomcat, httpclient

Sorry for the another question has already appearing everywhere. I'm very new to c# httpclient and I only need to write one small function for this once but I've been struggle to find a good example.

I'm building a windows store application using c# and I'm hoping to include a function to upload the file to my tomcat server through a web page I've created.

here is the piece of script to select a file and upload it to my server's drive.

```
<form method="post" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <input   type="file" name="uploadFile" />  
 <input   type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I've seen many answers regarding 'Upload httpclient(multipart/form-data)' but I haven't found one with easy to understand examples for rookies like me.

e.g. These [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19665601/1527840) seem really short but I have no idea how to apply it to my application. please let me know if there is any piece of example I can use to understand how to implement it.

update 1:
this is what I have at the moment...but it seems not working and there is no error message

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictureFolderPath, "Camera Roll", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentImagePath));
System.IO.Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);
System.Net.Http.HttpContent fileStreamContent = new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(fileStream);

using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
using (var formData = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent())
{ 
formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "uploadFile"); 
var response = client.PostAsync("http://10.66.65.93:8080/web/", formData).Result;
var response2 = 1;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"it seems not working"*? Do you receive some error code in response? Or request is not sent to server? Or server receive request but content is wrong? We are not able to help you without more details.